# How to Declare a Different Database Connection in laravel Controller

Tags: laravel, controller, laravel-5.4

I have a Controller and I need to set the Database for my Query Builder,
all is working but when I create new function I need to redeclare a connection,
What I need is to declare the connection so that the whole controller will be connecting with that database.

```
class CompanyInformationController extends Controller
{



    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function firstFunction()
    {

     $connection = DB::connection('fdis_1');

      return  $connection->getDatabaseName();

    }

    public function secondFunction()
    {
     // This is redundant
     $connection = DB::connection('fdis_1');

      return  $connection->getDatabaseName();

    }
}
```

Comment: Declare connection in constructure and use into whole controller

Comment: @RavindraBhanderi do you have example ?

Comment: ya i write ans for you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

in a class on controller

```
 private $connection;

 public function __construct()
    {
        $this->connection = DB::connection('fdis_1');

    }
```

now use into your method like

```
  $this->connection->getDatabaseName();
```

Comment: @MartneyAcha Welcome